# Un-nest JSON reponse in Postman

Tags: arrays, json, postman, export-to-csv

I have the following JSON body and want to un-nest the custom fields array. The end goal of this is to request this data and export to csv and I want each field to have its own column, including the custom fields which right now are all shoved into a single column for each entry. Any advice on how to do this in Postman?

```
[
    {
        "field1": null,
        "field2": null,
        "field3": null,
        "field4": null,
        "custom_fields": {
            "product_support": null,
            "consumer": null,
            "account_changes": null,
            "billing_support": null,
            "account": null,
            "collections": null,
            "resolution": null,
            "contact": null,
            "issue": null,
            "notes": null,
            "marketing_ad": null,
            "transport": null,
            "resolution": null,
            "modemgateway": null,
            "root_cause": null,
            "stb": null,
            "sale_made": null
        },
        "field5": null,
        "field6": null,
        "field7": null,
        "field8": null,
        "field9": null,
        "field10": null
```

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if postman can't do this on its own, but if you can pass the data through [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) *(no, not jQuery)*, you can do almost anything you want with it...

Comment: I appreciate the quick response. I will look into using jq to facilitate this. The API calls are going to be automated through MS Flow and then passed to csv for upload to a server, so I am not sure if I will be able to insert jq as a step into this process (especially seeing as I am not an IT admin), but I appreciate it nonetheless.